Adobe Acrobat is moving from a page to another like slides instead of scrolling, how can I fix this?
when I use adobe acrobat to view pdf files, some are viewed normally and I can scroll normally, stopping between to pages and it's completely fine. When I open other files, though, there appears a menu of the contents of the book, and I can't literally scroll, when I use the scroll on the touchpad or the mouth, it just moves me from page A to page B (I can't sit in between) this is frustrating and interrupting my work and study. When this problem occurs, I open the file in Chrome and it's working fine, but with Chrome, I can't save the last page as in Acrobat! How can I fix this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

there are many ways each version of acrobat can have prefered setting s applied by either User OR Author of PDF.
The desired mode is from the description continuous.

As a user there are usually several settings for when new files are opened  here is mine, related to that preference.

